# If $\{y_i\} \subset f([0,1])$ is increasing, there exists an monotonous $\{x_i\} \subset [0,1]$ such that $f(x_i)=y_i$?

Tags: analysis

Let $f \in C[0,1]$. If $\{y_i\} \subset f([0,1])$ is increasing, there exists an monotonous $\{x_i\} \subset [0,1]$ such that $f(x_i)=y_i$?

Intuitively, from the function image, it is true. and how to prove that?

Comment: What if $f$ is a decreasing function, such as $f(x) = -x$?

Comment: @Bungo thank you, I know my wrong, I edit that $\{x_i\}$ from increasing to monotonous.

Comment: @xunitc Hint: intermediate value property

Comment: @lc2r43 Thank you, by intermediate, there exists $x_i$ such that $f(x_i)=y_i$, but how to keep $x_i$ monotonous?